# Delete initial git commit of main branch

Tags: git, git-commit, git-reset

How can I delete all the commits **including initial commit** from the main branch of my git project?

I know we can do it by deleting .git directory and reinitializing the git project. However, I will miss all the commit history. So is there a way to do it using git commands?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to delete the branch and re-create it? Switch to a new branch, then `git -D main`.

Comment: Nope, I want to create new initial commit on main branch only.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was describing.

Comment: I tried doing that. I see the initial commit will never delete because when I create a new branch as you advised, the old initial commit will be the root commit. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you want to rename main branch and create a new *orphan* main branch:

```
$ git branch -m main main.bak
$ git checkout  --orphan main
Switched to a new branch 'main'
$ git log main
fatal: your current branch 'main' does not have any commits yet
```

Commits done on old main branch are now on main.bak branch.